# How to select next element using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to apply some design on the next element. But my problem is I am getting this error:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object] > label
```

Here's my selections:

BROWSE BY

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li>
        <input type="radio" id="cat-1" class="category_select" name="category_type" data-category-type="1" value="all_product" checked="checked" />
        <label for="cat-1"><span></span>All</label>     
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" id="cat-2" class="category_select" name="category_type" data-category-type="2" value="japanese_tea" />
        <label for="cat-2"><span></span>Japanese Tea</label>        
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" id="cat-3" class="category_select" name="category_type" data-category-type="3" value="black_vinegar" />
        <label for="cat-3"><span></span>Black Vinegar</label>       
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" id="cat-4" class="category_select" name="category_type" data-category-type="4" value="food" />
        <label for="cat-4"><span></span>Food</label>        
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" id="cat-5" class="category_select" name="category_type" data-category-type="5" value="cosmetic_health" />
        <label for="cat-5"><span></span>Cosmetic / Health</label>       
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" id="cat-6" class="category_select" name="category_type" date-category-type="6" value="others" />
        <label for="cat-6"><span></span>Others</label>      
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here's my JS:

```
$('.category_select').on('change', function() {

    var cat = $(this);
    var category_type = $(this).data('category-type');

    $(cat + ' > label').css({'color':'red'}); //wont apply some css why?

});
```

Can you help me with this?

Comment: `cat.next('label').css({'color':'red'});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next) traversal method to get the next sibling of an element

In your code `cat` is a jQuery object so when used in string concatenation your selector becomes `[object Object] > label`

```js
$('.category_select').on('change', function() {

  var cat = $(this);
  var category_type = $(this).data('category-type');

  cat.next('label').css({
    'color': 'red'
  }); //wont apply some css why?

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-unstyled">
  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="cat-1" class="category_select" name="category_type" data-category-type="1" value="all_product" checked="checked" />
    <label for="cat-1"><span></span>All</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="cat-2" class="category_select" name="category_type" data-category-type="2" value="japanese_tea" />
    <label for="cat-2"><span></span>Japanese Tea</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="cat-3" class="category_select" name="category_type" data-category-type="3" value="black_vinegar" />
    <label for="cat-3"><span></span>Black Vinegar</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="cat-4" class="category_select" name="category_type" data-category-type="4" value="food" />
    <label for="cat-4"><span></span>Food</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="cat-5" class="category_select" name="category_type" data-category-type="5" value="cosmetic_health" />
    <label for="cat-5"><span></span>Cosmetic / Health</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="cat-6" class="category_select" name="category_type" date-category-type="6" value="others" />
    <label for="cat-6"><span></span>Others</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly select the next `label` using the `id` attribute of selected input box

```
 $('.category_select').on('change', function() {
        var cat = this.id;
        var category_type = $(this).data('category-type');
       $("label").css({'color':'black'}) // Remove red color from previously selected item
        $("label[for='"+cat+"']").css({'color':'red'}); // Apply red color on selected item

    });
```

[JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/m7vb3eoj/7/)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use .next() selector for selecting the next element, instead $(cat + ' > label')

```
$('.category_select').on('change', function() {

    var cat = $(this);
    var category_type = $(this).data('category-type');

    cat.next('label').css({'color':'red'}); //syntax for selecting next in js

});
```

Hope this helped you out??